# Maven deploy -x gives Failed to deploy artifacts ....Access denied to: http://

Tags: java, maven, nexus, snapshot, maven-deploy-plugin

I am trying to run mvn deploy on my project
I am not getting any Error codes like 401,407 etc

But the logs are saying

```
Uploading to repo id: dav:http://snapshot repo link//parent-pom/2.0.0.
```

Then execution failed

```
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Reactor Summary:
[INFO]
[INFO] parent-pom 2.0.0-SNAPSHOT ........... SUCCESS [  9.264 s]
[INFO] project-name-one .................. SUCCESS [  8.086 s]
[INFO] project-name-two ..................... SUCCESS [ 37.332 s]
[INFO] project-name-three ...................... SUCCESS [ 20.625 s]
[INFO] project-name-four 2.0.0-SNAPSHOT ... FAILURE [ 19.265 s]
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 01:35 min
[INFO] Finished at: 2018-12-06T21:55:07-06:00
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------

[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-deploy-plugin:2.8.2:deploy (default-deploy) on project project-name-four: Failed to deploy artifacts: Could not transfer artifact project.groupid:project-name-one:pom:2.0.0-20181207.035505-1 from/to [repo id] (dav:http://repo/main/snapshot-repo): Access denied to: http://repo/main/snapshot-repo/project/group/id/project-name-one/2.0.0-SNAPSHOT/project-name-one-2.0.0-20181207.035505-1.pom -> [Help 1]
org.apache.maven.lifecycle.LifecycleExecutionException: Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-deploy-plugin:2.8.2:deploy (default-deploy) on project project-name-four: Failed todeploy artifacts: Could not transfer artifact project.groupid:project-name-one:pom:2.0.0-20181207.035505-1 from/to [repo id] (dav:http://repo/main/snapshot-repo): Access denied to: http://repo/main/snapshot-repo/project/group/id/project-name-one/2.0.0-SNAPSHOT/project-name-one-2.0.0-20181207.035505-1.pom
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:213)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:154)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:146)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject (LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:117)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject (LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:81)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.builder.singlethreaded.SingleThreadedBuilder.build (SingleThreadedBuilder.java:56)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute (LifecycleStarter.java:128)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:305)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:192)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute (DefaultMaven.java:105)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute (MavenCli.java:954)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain (MavenCli.java:288)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main (MavenCli.java:192)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0 (Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Method.java:498)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced (Launcher.java:289)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch (Launcher.java:229)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode (Launcher.java:415)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main (Launcher.java:356)
Caused by: org.apache.maven.plugin.MojoExecutionException: Failed to deploy artifacts: Could not transfer artifact project.groupid:project-name-one:pom:2.0.0-20181207.035505-1 from/to [repo id] (dav:http://repo/main/snapshot-repo): Access denied to: http://repo/main/snapshot-repo/project/group/id/project-name-one/2.0.0-SNAPSHOT/project-name-one-2.0.0-20181207.035505-1.pom
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.deploy.DeployMojo.deployProject (DeployMojo.java:284)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.deploy.DeployMojo.execute (DeployMojo.java:185)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo (DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:137)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:208)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:154)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:146)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject (LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:117)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject (LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:81)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.builder.singlethreaded.SingleThreadedBuilder.build (SingleThreadedBuilder.java:56)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute (LifecycleStarter.java:128)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:305)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:192)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute (DefaultMaven.java:105)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute (MavenCli.java:954)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain (MavenCli.java:288)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main (MavenCli.java:192)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0 (Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Method.java:498)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced (Launcher.java:289)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch (Launcher.java:229)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode (Launcher.java:415)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main (Launcher.java:356)
Caused by: org.apache.maven.artifact.deployer.ArtifactDeploymentException: Failed to deploy artifacts: Could not transfer artifact project.groupid:project-name-one:pom:2.0.0-20181207.035505-1 from/to [repo id] (dav:http://repo/main/snapshot-repo): Access denied to: http://repo/main/snapshot-repo/project/group/id/project-name-one/2.0.0-SNAPSHOT/project-name-one-2.0.0-20181207.035505-1.pom
    at org.apache.maven.artifact.deployer.DefaultArtifactDeployer.deploy (DefaultArtifactDeployer.java:146)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.deploy.AbstractDeployMojo.deploy (AbstractDeployMojo.java:171)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.deploy.DeployMojo.deployProject (DeployMojo.java:242)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.deploy.DeployMojo.execute (DeployMojo.java:185)
.
.
.
.

Caused by: org.eclipse.aether.deployment.DeploymentException: Failed to deploy artifacts: Could not transfer artifact project.groupid:project-name-one:pom:2.0.0-20181207.035505-1 from/to [repo id] (dav:http://repo/main/snapshot-repo): Access denied to: http://repo/main/snapshot-repo/project/group/id/project-name-one/2.0.0-SNAPSHOT/project-name-one-2.0.0-20181207.035505-1.pom
    at org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.DefaultDeployer.deploy (DefaultDeployer.java:295)
    at org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.DefaultDeployer.deploy (DefaultDeployer.java:223)
    at org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.DefaultRepositorySystem.deploy (DefaultRepositorySystem.java:384)
    at org.apache.maven.artifact.deployer.DefaultArtifactDeployer.deploy (DefaultArtifactDeployer.java:142)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.deploy.AbstractDeployMojo.deploy (AbstractDeployMojo.java:171)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.deploy.DeployMojo.deployProject (DeployMojo.java:242)
.
.
.
.

Caused by: org.eclipse.aether.transfer.ArtifactTransferException: Could not transfer artifact project.groupid:project-name-one:pom:2.0.0-20181207.035505-1 from/to [repo id] (dav:http://repo/main/snapshot-repo): Access denied to: http://repo/main/snapshot-repo/project/group/id/project-name-one/2.0.0-SNAPSHOT/project-name-one-2.0.0-20181207.035505-1.pom
    at org.eclipse.aether.connector.basic.ArtifactTransportListener.transferFailed (ArtifactTransportListener.java:52)
    at org.eclipse.aether.connector.basic.BasicRepositoryConnector$TaskRunner.run (BasicRepositoryConnector.java:365)
    at org.eclipse.aether.connector.basic.BasicRepositoryConnector.put (BasicRepositoryConnector.java:284)
    at org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.DefaultDeployer.deploy (DefaultDeployer.java:289)
.
.
.
.
Caused by: org.apache.maven.wagon.authorization.AuthorizationException: Access denied to: http://repo/main/snapshot-repo/project/group/id/project-name-one/2.0.0-SNAPSHOT/project-name-one-2.0.0-20181207.035505-1.pom
    at org.apache.maven.wagon.shared.http.AbstractHttpClientWagon.put (AbstractHttpClientWagon.java:409)
    at org.apache.maven.wagon.shared.http.AbstractHttpClientWagon.put (AbstractHttpClientWagon.java:336)
    at org.apache.maven.wagon.shared.http.AbstractHttpClientWagon.put (AbstractHttpClientWagon.java:303)
```

.
   .
   .
   .
    [ERROR]
    [ERROR]
    [ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
    [ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MojoExecutionException
    [ERROR]
    [ERROR] After correcting the problems, you can resume the build with the command
    [ERROR]   mvn  -rf :project-name-three

I tried to verify settings.xml and my pom distribution management..
As this is not generation any error code I couldn't figure code the exact problem

Answer (score 2):

There could be one of two things going on based upon the status codes 401 and 407. In case of a 401 then the artifact server (Nexus) requires authorization and authentication to publish artifacts. In this case you need to provide the required username and password. This can be done in the ~/.m2/settings.xml by adding something similar to this:

```
<servers>
  <server>
    <id>dav:http://snapshot</div>
    <username>youruser</username>
    <password>yourpass</password>
  </server>
</servers
```

The error code 407 indicates an entirely different problem. This usually means you have a proxy server between you and the artifact server that requires a login. This can usually be solved by adding a proxy configuration to the settings.xml with the required username and password. See the sample below from for a template.

```
<proxies>
    <!-- proxy
 | Specification for one proxy, to be used in connecting to the network.
 |
<proxy>
  <id>optional</id>
  <active>true</active>
  <protocol>http</protocol>
  <username>proxyuser</username>
  <password>proxypass</password>
  <host>proxy.host.net</host>
  <port>80</port>
  <nonProxyHosts>local.net|some.host.com</nonProxyHosts>
</proxy>
-->
</proxies>
```

Comment: Actually I said I am not getting any error code to define the problem...

Comment: You are getting access denied. Which would suggest an authorization issue with the deploy.

Comment: If it is access issue, then it should provide 401 error right ? .. or how can I verify whether I have access to release the snapshot version into nexus snapshot repo ?

Comment: If you are releasing to nexus then why use the dav protocol? This requires wagon and should not be needed for nexus.

Comment: Changing the username and password in settings.xml worked for me .. Thank you :)

Comment: @PriyankaAnjuri Please consider accepting the answer if you are satisifed.  It removes the ticket from the outstanding list and gives the answerer credit.